# Using Custom UI editor insert a new tab as the last tab in Excel Ribbon

Tags: xml, excel, vba, editor, ribbon

I want to insert a new tab after the last tab.  But the problem is that I don't know exactly what is the current last tab; it could be "Acrobat reader" or something else. How to accomplish this. I have that following code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
<tab id="MyCustomTab" label="MyTab" insertAfterMso="TabView">
<group id="customGroup1" label="First Tab">
<button id="customButton1" label="JG Button 1" imageMso="HappyFace" size="large" onAction="Callback1" />
<button id="customButton2" label="JG Button 2" imageMso="PictureBrightnessGallery" size="large" onAction="Callback2" />
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Undesired results? On cursory look this does add tab to end off standard ribbon.

Answer (score 5):

If you remove `insertAfterMso="TabView"` from the tab-tag in the ribbon-XML your tab will be placed to the far right, after the last tab:

```
<tab id="MyCustomTab" label="MyTab">
```